# Yet Another Relativity Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, relativity, thought-experiment

**Intro**

Thank you for reading.

I realize this looks like a long question, but its a homework-like/thought-experiment question, and I've tried to put as much work into it as possible before posting it, since I understand its often frustrating when people post homework-like questions without much work.

Hopefully, having put as much into it as I can will help guide those of you who respond. Thank you again!

---

**The Question**

Bob and Clark are standing on a truck.

The truck is moving towards the right relative to Alice, who is standing on a platform, at a velocity $v$.

Alice, Bob, and Clark all have clocks with them.

Just as Bob passes Alice, Bob sends a light signal to Clark.

Here's a little drawing to illustrate what I mean *(the light signal isn't drawn in. Also, ignore any vertical displacement between Alice and the truck)*:

[image]

All three characters have clocks, and all three clocks read $0$ as the message is sent, according to Bob.

What does Alice's clock read as the message is sent, according to Clark?

What does Alice's clock read as the message is received by Clark, according to Clark?

---

**My Work Thus Far**

*(I've derived as many results as I can...but I still am not sure of the answer)*

1. As Bob passes Alice, his clock reads $0$, Alice's clock reads $0$, and Clark's clock reads $0$ according to Bob.
2. The proper length of the truck is $L_P$. That is, as Bob passes Alice, Clark and Bob are $L_P$ away from one another according to both of them. Additionally, since they must both agree that Alice passed Bob just as the message was sent, they both see Clark as $L_P$ away from Alice.
3. The length of the truck according to Alice is $\frac{L_P}{\gamma}$. So, as Bob passes Alice, Clark and Alice are $\frac{L_P}{\gamma}$ away from one another according to Alice. Additionally, Clark is $\frac{L_P}{\gamma}$ away from her.
4. As Bob passes Alice, his clock reads $0$, Alice's clock reads $0$, but Bob's clock reads $\frac{-L_Pv}{c^2}$ according to Alice. That is, the Clark which Alice thinks is at a distance of $\frac{L_P}{\gamma}$ away from her when the message is sent is younger than Clark actually feels himself to be when the message is sent to him, by $\frac{L_Pv}{c^2}$ seconds.

*Notice that #3 and #4 explain one another...the fact that Alice thinks that Clark is $\frac{L_Pv}{c^2}$ seconds younger than Clark thinks he is when Bob sends the message is in agreeance with her thinking him to be at a distance of $\frac{L_P}{\gamma}$ away from her when Bob sends the message.*

*Sure enough, had Clark been $\frac{L_Pv}{c^2}$ seconds younger than he is when he thinks Alice sends the message, he would've considered Alice to be $L_P - v\frac{L_Pv}{c^2}=\frac{L_P}{\gamma^2}$ meters away from him, which is exactly what Alice (who sees Clark to be $\frac{L_P}{\gamma}$ meters away) would think Clark sees her to be from him due to length contraction at the moment Bob sends the message.*

5. The time which Alice feels pass before the message reaches Clark would be $\frac{L_P}{\gamma(c-v)}$. That's because according to Alice, the relative velocity between the light message and Clark is $c-v$, and his initial displacement from the light-source is $\frac{L_P}{\gamma}$.
6. Due to time dilation, the time which Alice would see pass for Clark before the message reaches him would be $=\frac{L_P}{\gamma^2(c-v)}$ Notice that this is longer than the time Clark would feel pass for himself.
7. The time on Clark's clock according to all three of them when the message gets to him would be $\frac{L_P}{c}$.

From Clark and Bob's point of view, this is easy to confirm - they started a distance of $L_P$ away from one another, and both see light travelling at a velocity of $c$. Clark's clock starts at $0$, thus $0+\frac{L_P}{c}=\frac{L_P}{c}$.

From Alice's point of view, its a little harder to confirm, but it turns out that $\frac{-L_Pv}{c^2}+\frac{L_P}{\gamma^2(c-v)}$, the starting time on Clark's clock according to Alice plus the time she sees him age for, equals $\frac{L_P}{c}$.

That is, although Alice thinks that the message took longer to get to Clark than Bob did, Alice also thought Clark was younger and closer to her when Bob sent the message than Bob did. So, Clark is the same age according to all of them when he receives the light message.

8. The distance which Bob and Clark move towards Alice's right, according to Alice, before Clark receives the message would be $v\frac{L_P}{\gamma(c-v)}$. That's their relative velocity to her multiplied by the time she saw them move for.

Therefor, the final distance from Alice to Clark once he receives the message, according to Alice, would be $\frac{L_P}{\gamma} + v\frac{L_P}{\gamma(c-v)} = \frac{L_Pc}{\gamma(c-v)}$

Since Alice is moving towards the left relative to Clark and Bob, they would see this final distance between Alice and Clark as $\frac{L_Pc}{\gamma^2(c-v)}$. And, sure enough, if we subtract the final distance between Clark and Bob according to Clark and Bob from the final distance between Clark and Alice according to Clark and Bob, we get: $\frac{L_Pc}{\gamma^2(c-v)}-L_P = \frac{L_Pv}{c}$, which is exactly what we expected them to say Alice would've moved to the left from Bob before the message got to Clark.

---

**One Final Thing...**

Okay, that's all my work thus far. My question is basically asking you to fill in the blanks in the following two paragraphs

When the message is first sent, Alice sees Clark as younger than he sees himself (he sees his clock says zero while she sees it say $\frac{-L_Pv}{c^2}$), while the Clark that actually sees the message being sent thinks that Alice's clock says_____________. Additionally, Clark thinks that Alice is further away from him $L_P$ than Alice thinks Clark is from her $\frac{L_P}{\gamma}$.

When the message is received, Clark sees Alice a distance of $\frac{L_Pc}{\gamma^2(c-v)}$, which is closer than what Alice sees him a distance away from her as $\frac{L_Pc}{\gamma(c-v)}$. Additionally, both Alice and Clark agree on what Clark's clock says $\frac{L_P}{c}$ while Clark thinks that Alice's clock says______________.

And finally, besides filling in the blanks, is there a way to intuitively explain in a concise way, the following three questions?

Why when the message is first sent Clark thinks Alice is further from him than she thinks he is from her, but when the message is received, Clark thinks Alice is closer to him than she thinks he is from her?

Why when the message is first sent Alice thinks Clark is younger than he sees himself as but when the message is received, Alice thinks Clark is the same age as he sees himself as?

And finally...

Why when the message is first sent Clark thinks Alice is (older,younger,same) than she sees herself as but when the message is received, Clark thinks Alice is (older, younger,same) than she sees herself as?

Thank you!

Comment: "According to Bob" and "According to Clark" are the same thing, which should simplify your analysis immensely.

Comment: @WillO okay, thank you! So both Clark and Bob would see $0$ on Alice's clock when the message is first sent, and would see $\frac{L_P}{c\gamma}$ on her clock once Clark recieves the message. Here's whats confusing me, however. When the message is first sent, Alice’s notion of Clark is a Clark that’s a past-self of the Clark that actually sees the message sent (he's younger and closer to her according to her than he thinks he is), while the Clark that sees the message being sent sees Alice exactly at the same age as she sees herself when the message is sent (her clock reads zero).

Comment: The above already seems like it would be wrong...I thought we needed to have some sort of symmetry in what Clark and Alice see of one another. However, it gets worse. When Clark receives the message, their interpretations switch. Now Alice’s notion of Clark agrees with the Clark that received the message (they both agree that Clark's clock says $\frac{L_P}{c}$). However, now Clark sees Alice as younger than she sees herself (he sees $\frac{L_P}{c\gamma}$ on her clock, while she sees $\frac{L_P}{\gamma(c-v)}$ on her clock) and sees her closer to him than she sees him to her.

Comment: Is there a way to intuitively explain why this happened? Why it is that their roles switched? Why it is that when the message was sent, Alice's concept of "NOW" at Clark's location was behind his concept of "NOW", while his concept of "NOW" at her location agreed with her concept of "NOW", but when Clark received the message...it was the opposite? I hope what I'm asking makes sense...

Comment: According to Bob/Clark, when the message is sent, everyone is the same age.  According to Alice, when the message is sent, Clark is younger than her.  You **built this in** to your problem setup and then complained that it seems asymmetric.  But if this counts as an asymmetry, it's only there because you put it there.  Are you also disturbed by the asymmetry between Clark's and Alice's genders?

Answer (score 2):

You are **way** overcomplicating this.

You seem to be interested  in (at least) three events:

$E$ --- Bob sends the message.

$F$ --- Clark receives the message.

$G$ --- Alice looks at her clock at what is, according to Clark, the same moment when Clark receives the message.

This picture shows all three events.  The thick red lines are Bob's and Clark's paths, which have slope $v$.  The skinny red line is a line of simultaneity according to Bob/Clark; it has slope $1/v$. The gold line is the path of the message. The length of the car, according to Alice, is L.

[image]
Now:

I.  Use algebra to find the coordinates of all these points in Alice's frame.

II.  Use the Lorentz transformation to convert the coordinates you've just found to the Bob/Clark frame.

III. If there's some other event you care about, add it to the picture and repeat steps I and II.

This will answer all of your questions.